# Magento Collection Filter not working with spaces

Tags: php, magento, collections, filter, mage

I have the following php code (running under magento 1.7.0.2) that finds a customer group with a particular code. The code works fine for groups that have no spaces in the code value, however it will not find any groups with a space in the code value, Can you locate the reason?

I don't want to change the code to use the group ID as this is not practical in this situation, can anyone help?

```
$theGrous = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection()->addFilter('customer_group_code', $groupName);
```

For example when the variable $groupName is 'Standard' I find results, when it is 'Standard Rate' I don't get it as it, this happens for any codes with spaces in them

thanks

Comment: Just made a test in 1.12.0.2 without any problems.
`
$groupName = 'test with space';
$theGrous = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection()->addFilter('customer_group_code', $groupName);
var_dump($theGrous->getFirstItem()->debug());
`

Resulting in:
`
  'customer_group_id' =>
  string(1) "5"
  'customer_group_code' =>
  string(15) "test with space"
  'tax_class_id' =>
  string(1) "3"
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for looking into it, in the end I changed the code to iterate over collection and manually compare each code, and it still didn't work! Turns out that there was a slight difference in the names which for reason I didn't notice so the original filter was working correctly after all!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is another option to get customer group name.

```
$group = Mage::getModel('customer/customer_group')->load($groupId);
$group->getName();
```

Comment: I believe MrTea means that he wants to match a customer_group on group_code not just getting the name of a group through loading a group by ID.